Did the Master of Ballantrae poison Chew?
The main plot of The Master of Ballantrae, by Robert Louis Stevenson, revolves around two brothers, who, over the course of their lives, become consumed with hatred for each other to the exclusion of everything else. The novel begins with the Jacobite rising of 1745. The brothers’ father,  Lord Durrisdeer, suggests that one of them should join the rebels while the other fights on the side of the English, so that no matter who wins, their estate will not be confiscated. A coin is flipped to determine which side each brother fights on, and the Master of Ballantrae, who is the villain of this book, joins the uprising.
After the failure of the rebellion, Ballantrae is exiled. Some time later, he and another exiled rebel, Colonel Burke, find themselves in America. They are wanted by the British, and thus need to escape the British colonies. They hire an Indian guide1, Chew, to escort them through the wilderness to a French fort on Lake Champlain.
When they are nearly there, Chew dies. An excerpt from Colonel Burke's memoirs explains:

We were come to the most critical portion of our course, where we might equally expect to fall into the hands of French or English, when a terrible calamity befell us. Chew was taken suddenly sick with symptoms like those of poison, and in the course of a few hours expired in the bottom of the canoe. 

Much later, when the brothers meet again in New York. Ballantrae’s brother (now Lord Durrisdeer) says about Ballantrae:

His reputation awaits him; I have prepared a welcome for my brother. Indeed, fortune has served me; for I found here a merchant of Albany who knew him after the ’45 and had mighty convenient suspicions of a murder: some one of the name of Chew it was, another Albanian.2

The question is: did Ballantrae poison Chew?
 Arguments against:
It would be an immensely stupid thing for Ballantrae to do. After Chew dies, Ballantrae and Burke are left alone in the wilderness, where they could easily be killed if they happen to encounter hostile Indians. As it is, Chew's death leads to disaster: they get totally lost, accidentally destroy their canoe, have a big argument and get separated, and are only saved because they each happen to run into a party of Frenchmen who take them to Fort St. Frederick.
Arguments for:
Ballantrae and Burke are carrying a fortune in ill-gotten gains. Ballantrae may be afraid that Chew will murder them and steal their treasure—this is undoubtedly what Ballantrae would do if he were in Chew’s place. In fact, Ballantrae has already killed two men so as to be able to split the treasure two ways rather than four. Furthermore, Ballantrae is an excessively confident man, and he believes he knows how to reach the fort without Chew's guidance: Chew dies when they are quite close to their destination, and it is apparent that Ballantrae has been listening very carefully to Chew’s description of their route (although clearly not carefully enough).
My question:
Is there any further evidence one way or the other as to whether Ballantrae poisoned Chew?
Or, on the other hand, is there some indication that Stevenson deliberately left this ambiguous?

1 An Indian guide is not himself an Indian, but somebody who is friendly with the Indians, speaks Indian languages, and can safely escort travelers through Indian territory.
2 Albanian meaning from Albany, New York. The Albanian who is accusing him is probably one that Ballantrae encountered earlier in the novel.

I think the author's intent is that we should have the same doubt about Chew's fate as the brother.

@mikado: Since the two brothers hate each other, and since the Master of Ballantrae has no principles whatsoever, I expect that Ballantrae's brother is absolutely certain that he killed Chew. Whether this is correct is a different question.
